# MVC Model validation not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
         <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                 @*<input type="text" name="pop_cust_name" id="pop_cust_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name">*@
                 @*@Html.TextBox("Customer_Name", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Full Name" })*@
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer_Name, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Full Name" })
                 @Html.HiddenFor( m => m.Customer_ID)
                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Customer_Name, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="col col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                @*<input type="text" name="pop_cust_mob" id="pop_cust_mob" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Mobile">*@
                @*@Html.TextBox("Customer_Mobile", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Mobile" })*@
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer_Mobile, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Mobile" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Customer_Mobile, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="col col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                @*<input type="Email" name="pop_cust_email" id="pop_cust_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email">*@
                @*@Html.TextBox("Customer_Email", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Email" })*@
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer_Email, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Email" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Customer_Email, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="height:10px"></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                @*<input type="text" name="pop_cust_company" id="pop_cust_company" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name">*@
                @*@Html.TextBox("Customer_Company", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Company Name" })*@
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer_Company, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Company Name" })
            </div>

            <div class="col col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                @*<input type="text" name="pop_cust_fax" id="pop_cust_fax" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Fax">*@
                @*@Html.TextBox("Customer_Fax", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Fax" })*@
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer_Fax, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Fax" })
            </div>

            <div class="col col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                @*<input type="text" name="pop_cust_other" id="pop_cust_other" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Other">*@
                @*@Html.TextBox("Customer_Other", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Other" })*@
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer_Other, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Other" })
             </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="height:10px"></div>

          <div class="col col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8"></div>

          <div class="col col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox">Same as billing address
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="height:10px"></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                @*<textarea class="form-control" name="pop_cust_bill_address" rows="3" placeholder="Billing address"></textarea>*@
                @*@Html.TextArea("Customer_BillingAddresss", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Billing address" })*@
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Customer_BillingAddresss, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Billing Address" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Customer_BillingAddresss, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">

                @*<textarea class="form-control" name="pop_cust_ship_address" rows="3" placeholder="Shipping address"></textarea>*@
                @*@Html.TextArea("Customer_ShippingAddress", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Shipping address" })*@
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Customer_ShippingAddress, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Shipping Address" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Customer_ShippingAddress, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="height:10px"></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                @*<input type="text" name="pop_cust_pan_no" id="pop_cust_pan_no" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter PAN No">*@
                @*@Html.TextBox("Customer_PanNo", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter PAN No" })*@
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer_PanNo, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter PAN No" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Customer_PanNo, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                @*<input type="text" name="pop_cust_gst_num" id="pop_cust_gst_num" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter GSTIN">*@
                @*@Html.TextBox("Customer_GSTIN", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter GSTIN" })*@
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer_GSTIN, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter GSTIN" })
            </div>
            <div class="col col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                @*<input type="text" name="pop_cust_gst_clr" id="pop_cust_gst_clr" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter CLR">*@
                @*@Html.TextBox("Customer_CLR", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter CLR" })*@
                @Html.TextBoxFor(M => M.Customer_CLR, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter CLR" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="height:10px"></div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                    @*<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Note"></textarea>*@
                    @*@Html.TextArea("Customer_Note", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Note" })*@
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Customer_Note, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Note" })
                </div>

            </div>

        <div class="col col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer" >
         <button type="submit" name="save_pop" id="save_pop" class="btn btn-success" formaction = '@Url.Action("AddCustomer", "Customers")'>Save</button> 
        <button type="submit" name="update_pop" id="update_pop" style="display:none" class="btn btn-success" formaction='@Url.Action("UpdateCustomer", "Customers")'>Update</button> 
        @*<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddCustomer", "Customers")'" />*@

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My controller code is

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddCustomer(CustomerEntities customerentities)
{
    customerentities.Customer_Name = Request["Customer_Name"].ToString();
    customerentities.Customer_Mobile = Request["Customer_Mobile"].ToString();
    customerentities.Customer_Email = Request["Customer_Email"].ToString();
    customerentities.Customer_Company = Request["Customer_Company"].ToString();
    customerentities.Customer_Fax = Request["Customer_Fax"].ToString();
    customerentities.Customer_Other = Request["Customer_Other"].ToString();
    customerentities.Customer_BillingAddresss = Request["Customer_BillingAddresss"].ToString();
    customerentities.Customer_ShippingAddress = Request["Customer_ShippingAddress"].ToString();
    customerentities.Customer_PanNo = Request["Customer_PanNo"].ToString();
    customerentities.Customer_GSTIN = Request["Customer_GSTIN"].ToString();
    customerentities.Customer_CLR = Request["Customer_CLR"].ToString();
    customerentities.Customer_Note = Request["Customer_Note"].ToString();
    customerentities.User_ID = 1;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        CustomerRepository custRepo = new InvoiceProcessingSystem.CustomerRepository();

        if (custRepo.AddCustomer(customerentities))
        {
            TempData["AddCustomer"] = "Customer details added successfully";
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", customerentities);
}
```

As there is no view for controller AddCustomer so i am redirecting it to Index view with along with the model, because i am trying to do CRUD in a single view.

At Last my Model code is :

```
public int Customer_ID { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Customer Name is required")]
public string Customer_Name { get; set; }

//[Required(ErrorMessage = "Customer Mobile is required")]
[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
[RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid Mobile number")]        
public string Customer_Mobile { get; set; }

//[Required(ErrorMessage = "Customer Email is required")]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid Email Address")]
public string Customer_Email { get; set; }

//[Required(ErrorMessage = "Customer Company is required")]
public string Customer_Company { get; set; }

public string Customer_Fax { get; set; }

public string Customer_Other { get; set; }

//[Required(ErrorMessage = "Customer Billing is required")]
[MaxLength(500)]
public string Customer_BillingAddresss { get; set; }

//[Required(ErrorMessage = "Customer Shipping Address is required")]
[MaxLength(500)]
public string Customer_ShippingAddress { get; set; }

//[Required(ErrorMessage = "Customer PAN No. is required")]
[RegularExpression(@"[A-Z]{5}\d{4}[A-Z]{1}", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid Mobile number")]
public string Customer_PanNo { get; set; }

//[Required(ErrorMessage = "Customer GSTIN is required")]
public string Customer_GSTIN { get; set; }

//[Required(ErrorMessage = "Customer CLR is required")]
public string Customer_CLR { get; set; }

public string Customer_Note { get; set; }

//[Required(ErrorMessage = "Customer Name is required")]
public int User_ID { get; set; }
```

I am not quite sure of what i am doing wrong here as i am new to MVC but i have don't validations previously using models but i am not able to figure out that's whats wrong with my code here.

Comment: Your code block of form controls, submit button, validation message, etc should be inside Html.Form or Ajax.Form. Do you get the POST method getting called?

Comment: Yes the post method in the controller is getting called but somehow the validations are not working and yes i have wrapped the form inside Html.Beginform element

Comment: What value do you see for "Model.IsValid" when you debug the POST action?

Comment: Not related, but get rid of all those `customerentities.Customer_Name = Request["Customer_Name"].ToString();` lines of code. The `customerentities` parameter is already bound with the values from the form

Comment: Also, try enabling client-side validation by adding <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" /> key in web.config, if not.

Comment: What is you problem. Are you saying that you do not get client side validation (have you include the relevant scripts). And if `ModelState` is not valid, then you return the view, not redirect.

Comment: Why have you commented out various validation requirements? What are you inputting into the form and what fields are you expecting to fail? You may want to reduce your code to the minimum amount in order to replicate the issue.

Comment: Can you be more specific about *"not working"*? Most of us here would love to help you but we can only help so far as we have an actual error to address. *"Not working"* is not a problem description that allows us to help you.

Comment: Actually the problem is that i am doing crud on a single view so i am returning redirecttoaction rather than returning the view and i am returning the model along with the action to but the validations are not firing

Comment: You need to return the view, not redirect! And you need to buy yourself a good book or go to the MVC site and work though the tutorials to learn the basics.

Comment: the problem is the same i don't have a view for that action method, i am trying to perform all the CRUD in single view, which i did, but the validations are not firing

Comment: I have to redirect, there must be some way to fire validations when i am redirecting

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting client side validations, Make sure following:

Step 1: Add the following in your web.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

Step 2: Refer to `jquery.validate.js` in `index.cshtml`

Comment: Does the `appSettings` tab need to have the ` characters in it?

Comment: Not required. Those characters were included while formatting in stackoverflow

Comment: Thought as much. Figured I should get clarification anyway. I've removed those characters from the code block.

Comment: Not working i think that there is some issue with the model